# Calling the items.add method twice causes the two items to overlap on the card

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4

Here is my add item code:

```
myapp.cards.vehicleInfo.items.add(
       new Ext.List({ ...})
)
```

If after this I then do:

```
myapp.cards.vehicleInfo.items.add(
        new Ext.Panel(
        {html: 'test' }
        )
    );
```

The panel with 'test' appears on top of my list (overlapping), rather than vertically below it. I have tried doing a componenet dolayout inbetween adding the two items.

Any ideas? If I only do one or the other of the above it works as expected but if I do both together it leads to the above behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dock the panel to the bottom.

```
myapp.cards.vehicleInfo.dockedItems.add( new Ext.Panel(
    {html: 'test' }
    )
);
```

**Update**

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model  : 'Contact',
    data: [
        {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
        {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
        {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
        {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'}
    ]
});

new Ext.Application({
    launch: function() {
       var panel =  new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id:'thePanel',
            layout: 'vbox',
            style: 'background-color:darkblue',
            scroll:'vertical'
        });
//do this in your dynamically called function
    var list = new Ext.List({
        id :'theList',
        itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
        store: store1,
        width: '100%',
        scroll:false
    });


var smallPanel = new Ext.Panel({layout: 'auto',width:'100%',height:200,style:'background-color:darkgreen;color:white',html:"Hello I'm the panel"});
    panel.items.add(list);
    panel.items.add(smallPanel);
    panel.doLayout();               
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still overlapping. The first item I am adding is a list which is linked to a store being loaded. I also tried adding your code to the callback from the store so that it is only docked after the store is loaded but still no success.

Comment: Ok I added the config option dock: bottom to the panel and it now appears at the bottom of the card. The remaining problem now is that is doesn't scroll along with the list item above it. It's static like a toolbar.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but whatever it is you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is in the title of the question - add two items to the card but they overlap. You proposed docking the second panel item to the bottom of the card. Your code didn't quite work so I corrected it. However this isn't giving me the desired outcome as having the second item docked to the bottom of the card means it doesn't flow on after the first item when scrolling downwards, it is always present as you would expect from a docked item.

Comment: Do you need to have separate panel for each list item? Or have a panel only shown to the last / first item? What else is on the screen? What do you need this panel for? Do you plan to add buttons to it or just display text? There a couple of ways to achieve this things but I need to know the purpose of this panel and list.

Comment: The panel is actually going to be a form but I am using panel as an example. Rendering the panel/form within the list isn't an option as the list is populated via an xtemplate. I have on the page a card(which is just a panel), a toolbar docked at the top, and then I am trying to add two items to the card - the list and the panel/form. I just need one panel/form and I want it to appear at the end of the list. I will be adding two buttons to the panel. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the effort but unfortunately I cannot adopt this approach. The list and panel are added programatically/dynamicly hence why I am using the 'add' method in my original question and not just specifying them in the configuration object of the panel. It's not possible for me to have the list specified as an item in the card.

Comment: You can still add them dynamically. I have updated the answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the layout option in the container to which you are adding Panels. I've had the same issue last week, and seting layout property to layout : {type : 'vbox', align : 'stretch' } provided me with a nice one column layout. I'm not sure if this is the issue, but try it anyway:)