# Dyanmic forms from json file in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, touch

How can I create dynamic form where all the fields are coming from a  json file in sencha touch?

**(Additional details transferred from "answer")**

My json looks like it 
{

```
  success: true,
 data: [
     {xtype: "textfield", title: "label1", name: "textfield1"},
     {xtype: "emailfield", title: "label2", name: "textfield2"},
     {xtype: "passwordfield", title: "label3", name: "textfield3"},
     {xtype: "button", title: "button", name: "button"}




  ]
}
```

I want  a sepearte controller and a view.
i did it in a single controller file like this

```
       form = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyDataView');
var test=this;



                var ajax = Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'contacts.json',
            method: 'get',
            success: function(response)
             {

            console.log(response);               
            response = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                           this.hello=response;
            console.log(response.data.length);  
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) 
                {
                    form.add({
                        xtype: response.data[i].xtype,
                        id:response.data[i].title,
                                        action:response.data[i].title,
                        label: response.data[i].title,
                        name: response.data[i].name

                             });


                                                }


                    console.log(form.getValues());

                                form.setLayout();


                                form.show(document.body);
                Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(form,{type: 'flip', direction: 'right'});

 }
```

there is some problem i m facing regarding the utton tap event and if multiple buttons are there giving event to them is not yet possible for me ....can anybody help me regarding this ..

Comment: You should include more details in your question, like the structure of your json, what you've tried so far and there you ran into problems. As it stands now, your question is too broad and vague.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something yet?

You can just create the form in the file like something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [ //...
    ]
}
```

Then you can load your file in, and decode it into a variable.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'yourform.json',
    success: function(response){
        var formInJson = response.responseText;
        var form = Ext.JSON.decode(formInJson);
        //... do something with your form
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am getting the response back from the server ok, but getting this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getItemId'